# Doctrine annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Annotation\Entity" in class does not exist or cannot be autoloaded

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I'm following the [Doctrine *Getting Started*](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) tutorial to the letter.

I've created the `Product` class (by copy/pasting from the tutorial, to ensure no typos), but when I run

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

I get `[OK] No Metadata Classes to process`. It seems this is because of the `useSimpleAnnotationReader` parameter of `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` defaulting to `true`.

So if I change this to `false`:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode, null, null, false);
```

Running the `schema-tool:create` command above now returns:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Annotation\Entity" in class Product does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

when it should execute and then dump out the SQL generated.

Searching on SO and elsewhere, it seems this problem is commonly caused by using forward- instead of backward-slashes in the annotations (which I haven't) or other typos in the Product entity (which I copy/pasted), or using Doctrine as part of a wider framework (Zend, Symfony).

My `Product.php`:

```
<?php
// src/Product.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try use the following statement:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

instead of:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation as ORM;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Incredible that the docs are wrong. As someone who is just learning Doctrine, is there an explanation you could add (that isn't obvious to everyone else!)?

Comment: hi @AdamHopkinson the only problem is that the doc is outdated :(